# opencv traincascade error?

Tags: opencv

I ran traincascade with the following parameters

```
traincascade -data haarcascade -vec samples.vec -bg negatives.dat -nstages 20 -minhitrate 0.999 
-maxfalsealarm 0.5 -npos 1000 -nneg 2000 -precalcValBufSize 1024 
-precalcIdxBufSize 1024  -w 20 -h 20 -featureType LBP -mode ALL
```

but I get the following output:

```
PARAMETERS:
cascadeDirName: haarcascade
vecFileName: samples.vec
bgFileName: negatives.dat
numPos: 2000
numNeg: 1000
numStages: 20
precalcValBufSize[Mb] : 1024
precalcIdxBufSize[Mb] : 1024
stageType: BOOST
featureType: LBP
sampleWidth: 20
sampleHeight: 20
boostType: GAB
minHitRate: 0.995
maxFalseAlarmRate: 0.5
weightTrimRate: 0.95
maxDepth: 1
maxWeakCount: 100

===== TRAINING 0-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   2000 : 2000
NEG count : acceptanceRatio    1000 : 1
Precalculation time: 0.415
+----+---------+---------+
|  N |    HR   |    FA   |
+----+---------+---------+
|   1|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   2|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   3|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   4|   0.9995|    0.651|
+----+---------+---------+
|   5|   0.9955|    0.499|
+----+---------+---------+
END>
**OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (No element name has been given) in unknown function, file C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2/core/operations.hpp, line 2908**
```

**any body knows why this happens?**

Answer (score 0):

Use this command

```
traincascade -data haarcascade -vec samples.vec -bg negatives.dat -numStages 20 -minHitRate 0.999 -maxFalseAlarm 0.5 -numPos 1000 -numNeg 2000 -precalcValBufSize 1024 
-precalcIdxBufSize 1024  -w 20 -h 20 -featureType LBP -mode ALL
```